# Specifying figure width as html percentages in quarto yaml

Tags: html, css, r, yaml, quarto

I'm trying to set the HTML figure width for a whole project, 60% of the page width, I'm trying:

```
---
format:
  html:
    default-image-extension: png
    fig-width: "60%"
---

![something](images/test_image)
```

but it gives the error:

```
x The value "60%" is of type string.
i The error happened in location format:html:fig-width.
```

changing this to 0.5 doesn't bring up an error, but the figures remain the same size. I can change figures individually, but would like a blanket YAML statement

Comment: `fig-width` can only take numeric values and if you are using `knitr` engine the `fig-width` value will be passed in `inches` unit.

Comment: ah, so I take it there is no way to set all images as a % width in the YAML, and this is a CSS issue?

Comment: You can set the figure width as "60%" for the images generated by r code chunk using knitr option `out.width` in yaml section. But that will not affect the images embedded using markdown syntax. For markdown imgaes, I think using css would be easy option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I have already commented, `fig-width` can only take values in numeric. So to set figure width in percentage unit, another option could be using `out-width` which can take values in different units (px, cm, mm, in, inch and %). But it seems specifying `out-width` does not work from the yaml. So you can use the knitr option `out.width` (note the `.` in between instead of `-`) to set the global figure width for images generated from code chunks.

But this `out.width` will not affect the markdown images and for that you may use css.

````
---
title: Specifying fig width in percentage unit
format:
  html: 
    default-image-extension: png
knitr:
  opts_chunk:
    out.width: "60%"
---

## Plot

```{r}
plot(rnorm(1000))
```

## Markdown Images

![A cute Dog](dog.jpg)

```{css, echo=FALSE}
img.figure-img {
  width: 60%;
}
```
````